# Can I use multiple IDs in a single shellscript or use one script to activate several others that are copies but with different IDs in them?

Tags: bash, scripts

Let me start by saying I'm sorry if this is a common question or was already answered but I personally wasn't able to find one (probably using wrong terminology).

I'm not experienced with scripts, or programming in general, but I do have an application that I use 90% of the time on my laptop to turn off my keyboard since I'm a big fan of synergy and because its a warm place my cat likes to chill. The problem is he has a habit of hitting the power button or track pad which aren't turned off from the script so I was hoping to find a QoL solution rather than having to activate all three scripts individually on startup. At present I'm using an old solution I found here that uses the keyboards ID and a text file to enable/disable it as well as give me a notification of what state its in. Like I said I did try looking around for an answer as well as trying out what I thought might work but no dice.

```
#!/bin/bash
Icon="/home/austin/Pictures/Icon.png"
Icoff="/home/austin/Pictures/Icoff.png"
fconfig=".keyboard" 
id=11

if [ ! -f $fconfig ];
then
    echo "Creating config file"
    echo "enabled" > $fconfig
    var="enabled"
else
    read -r var< $fconfig
    echo "keyboard is : $var"
fi

if [ $var = "disabled" ];
then
    notify-send -i $Icon "Enabling keyboard..." \ "ON - Keyboard connected !";
    echo "enable keyboard..."
    xinput enable $id
    echo "enabled" > $fconfig
elif [ $var = "enabled" ]; then
    notify-send -i $Icoff "Disabling Keyboard" \ "OFF - Keyboard disconnected";
    echo "disable keyboard"
    xinput disable $id
    echo 'disabled' > $fconfig
fi
```

Like I said I'm also fine with just copy/pasting the script with different IDs but I'd like to have just a single button to press on my taskbar rather than three for QoL. I'm sorry if this came off as confusing or already answered but I'd be super grateful for an answer or a point in the right direction.